# What does "material" mean in this clause?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

I want to know what does material mean in this clause, and are there any other synonyms?

"Capitalization of the quoted material depends on the material itself."

Comment: Welcome to ELL!  This question is difficult to answer without knowing the context.  What is the source of the text?  From the dictionary definition of "material", which definition(s) do you think might apply?  What do you think the answer might be?  (To improve your question, use the **[Edit]** button on your question and add details, please.)  Please read the "[Contributor's Guide to ELL](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4783/contributors-guide)" and [Details Please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/details-please).  Keep contributing and welcome!

Comment: Notice that "capitalization" could mean this is **about English grammar**, but this same sentence could be used by a **financial analyst** to describe the ***tax treatment of business assets!*** (Capitalization also means to treat something as [capital](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capital_(economics)) -- an asset -- rather than as an ordinary [business expense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expense).)

Comment: Sometimes "material" can be a very general word, almost like "it" or "this".  If you asked the question "Capitalization of this depends on this itself", and asked what "this" was referring to, we would request you provide more surrounding context to get more information.   Can you post the rest of the paragraph?